# str.replace within a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jquery function as

```
function sendValue(str){
    $.post("test.php",{ sendValue: str },
    function(data){
        $('#display').html(data.returnValue);
    }, "json");
}
```

I want to replace space within the string. I thought I can do this by adding

```
str.replace(" ", "+");
```

to the second line of the function. But it did not work. I know very basic of javascript. How to replace " " with "+" in the string before posting data to test.php?

Comment: It would need to be the *first* line of the function body, not the second. You POST `str` to the server on the first line currently, so you need to do the replace before that.

Comment: I meant second line, pushing $.post to third line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `str.replace(/\s/g , "+")` instead. (`/\s/` is the regex escape for whitespace).

Also are you trying to encode the string as a URL? You could use `encodeURIComponent(str)` which is a built in javascript method.

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be the opposite

```
str.replace("+", " ");
```

I would try using

```
.replace(/ /g," ");
```

though.

Comment: No... from the question: "How to replace " " with "+""